# validating an email with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning about simple javascript form validation and I am just curious why my email validation is not working. I am trying to grab the information from the email input field and run my function with the RegEx in it. Any help would be appreciated.

fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6SWj4/

```
    (function(){


        var emailAddr = document.getElementById("f_email").value;
        console.log(emailAddr);

    //    console.log(email.test(str));
    //
    //    if(email.test(str) == true){
    //        console.log("true");
    //    }else{
    //        console.log("false");
    //    }

        myform.onsubmit = function(e){

            //Below is one example of the validateField call with an argument.
            //You must dynamically retrieve the ID name from the DOM/HTML.

            validateField(emailAddr);  //id = is the form input field ID


            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        };


        var validateField = function(inputName){

            if (inputName.name === 'f_email'){
                var pattern = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
                var emailVal = new RegExp(pattern);
                //You will need to create an else-if statement for each input field id.  The
                //      format will be similar to the above IF statement.


            }else{
                console.log("not valide");
            }

            var pass = emailVal.test(inputName);
            console.log(pass);

            var errorMsg = inputName.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling;

            if (!pass || inputName.value.length < 2){
                errorMsg.style.display='block';
                inputName.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            } else if (pass && inputName.value.length > 5){
                errorMsg.style.display='none';
                inputName.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
            } else {
                errorMsg.style.display='none';
                inputName.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            };
        };

    })();  // end wrapper
```

Comment: `my email validation is not working` how is it not working? Does it generate error messages? Does it just do nothing? "Doesn't work" just doesn't work for a good question.

Comment: Your e-mail validation really shouldn't be any more complex than "Does it have an @ symbol in it?" If it does, great - send them an e-mail including a link that they then use to verify the e-mail address is valid (and that they actually own it - you'd be surprised how many people sign up for things with an e-mail address that isn't theirs). That said... `var pass = emailVal.test(inputName);` should probably be `var pass = emailVal.test(inputName.value);` - you need to pass its value, not the actual input element.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify. There are no syntax errors. The problem is even when I enter a proper email in the field is comes back with an error. I think because I am not getting the string from the input field.

Comment: first of all, you´re getting the email value at the beggining before you write any value. You have to do the 'document.getElementById("f_email").value;' inside of "onsubmit" funcion

Comment: [You cannot validate email adresses using regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems from getting the value of the input on page load, not after user has entered anything. Try:

```
    myform.onsubmit = function(e){

        /* get value withing submit handler*/

        var emailAddr = document.getElementById("f_email").value;
        console.log(emailAddr);

        //Below is one example of the validateField call with an argument.
        //You must dynamically retrieve the ID name from the DOM/HTML.

        validateField(emailAddr);  //id = is the form input field ID


        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    };
```

ALso flaw in `validateField()`. Argument expected is `inpuname` but you are passing in email input value

Answer (score 0):

You have many errors in the code. First what i said you on the comments, you have to do the `document.getElementById("f_email").value;` inside of `onsubmit` function. You are also declaring variables inside something and using it out of it, for example `emailVal` that you declare inside the `if`. That cannot work, you have to declare it before the `if`. check with the javascript console these little errors.